# How to save image in Microsoft SQL Database on Azure from Android app?

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to find an easiest way to store and image from Android app in SQL Database on Azure. I created Azure Mobile App and I have sample project with TodoList table on my database. The client (Android app) project can save new text item to this database. How can I save image?

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, to store image from Android App to SQL Azure is that encode an image using Base64 to a byte array as an entity attribute to save it as a blob column via the backend of Azure Mobile App using NodeJS/C# on SQL Azure.

However, to save images to SQL Azure or other RDBMS is not a good idea. The correct & best way is that using Azure Blob Storage to store images or other files. There is a good [blog](http://chrisrisner.com/Storing-Images-from-Android-in-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services) which introduces how to store image from Android on Azure Mobile, I think it's very helpful that you can refer to.